# How to create a dashboard widget for one user

Tags: widgets, users, dashboard, id

I will start by warning you that my programming skill is limited.

I need to create a dashboard widget that will display in the WP dashboard for the users with the user_id=21.

So far I have tried the following code, but it isn't working:

```
function my_catdb() {
echo '<a href="http://xxxxxxxxxxx.org/?frm_display=single-catproblem">View the Problem Problem Database.</a>';
}
/**
 * add Dashboard Widget via function wp_add_dashboard_widget()
 */
function my_catdb_setup() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget( 'my_catdb', __( 'Cataloging Problem Database' ), 'my_catdb'         );
}
/**
 * use hook, to integrate new widget
 */
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {  
if ( $user_id = 21 ) {
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'my_wp_dashboard_setup');
} 
}
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: In what way is it not working? Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for `wp_loaded` to use `get_current_user_id()`.

Example:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpse_80061_load_dashboard_widget' );

function wpse_80061_load_dashboard_widget()
{
    if ( 1 === get_current_user_id() )
        add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'wpse_80061_add_dashboard_widget' );
        // your function:
        // add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'my_catdb_setup' );
}

function wpse_80061_add_dashboard_widget()
{
    wp_add_dashboard_widget(
        'wpse_80061_widget',
        'Hey!',
        'wpse_80061_render_dashboard_widget'
    );
}

function wpse_80061_render_dashboard_widget()
{
    echo 'hey!';
}
```

For a dashboard widget with more details see my plugin [T5 Table size dashboard widget](https://gist.github.com/4471448).

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help, but I'm not sure what to replace to make it work with my existing code.

Comment: @Sayid See my update. I have inserted a comment where you can call your function.